# Redirect from back-end to angular2 component

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, angular

Let's say I have web api controller. After executing some logic I want to redirect to provided redirectUrl passing some values. For example:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
{
    var redirectUrl = "some_url#parameter1=value1";
    return Redirect(redirectUrl);
}
```

For client side application I am using Angular2 and what I am trying to achieve is to redirect to my component based on `redirectUrl` and execute specific method in my angular2 component. What is the best approach to do it?

Answer (score 0):

We did something similar to this on our project.  But instead we let the client handle the redirect logic & URL building.  We only passed back in the response data to build the url.

```
http.post("someUrl").subscribe((response) => {
  // build URL and redirect based on response
});
```

Another approach we tried was to redirect to a static URL.  This was messy with Url Building as our .net side didn't have good support for matrix urls.